# How can i use event before add to cart ? if it exists at all - Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

Is there an event to `before_add_to_cart` or `add_to_cart_before`? 
Or What can I use instead of a **before add to cart** event ?
Thanks

Comment: I need to stop adding to the cart, if the price is below $ 60, can this event help me? thanks for answer Prathap Gunasekaran

Comment: Which version of Magento 2 you are using?

Comment: Keyur Shah  Magento version is 2.2.6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is an event(`checkout_cart_product_add_before`) before adding the product into the cart but from the Magento 2.3.X please check [this link for Magento 2.3.x](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart.php#L385)

But you are using Magento 2.2.6 version and in this version, [this event does not exist](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.6/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart.php#L374)  so I would suggest you use a [plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) feature of Magento.

So in your case, you want to restrict adding the product into the cart with your magic condition so go with `before` plugin on [`addProduct(..)`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart.php#L366) method.

Please define plugin in your `di.xml`

```
 <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
        <plugin name="prevent_add_to" type="Example\Sample\Plugin\PreventAddToCart"/>
    </type>
```

Now define your plugin class

```
<?php

namespace Example\Sample\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class PreventAddToCart
{

    public function beforeAddProduct(Cart $subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {
        if (!something) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__("ha ha"));
        }
        return [$productInfo,$requestInfo];
    }
}
```

Here `if (!something) {` replace with your magic condition(price is less than 60)

maybe you have a question to get the product price so you can easily get it from `$productInfo` because is product object.

*Note: I am assuming that you already know how to create a module in Magento 2*

Comment: Cool thank you and please explain the params part why it differs from after and before and how to handle such and that would be helpful

Comment: I think you should read the https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Keyur Shah  thanks very much for help , yes i know how create module

Comment: Thank you +1 for the answer and it adds some clarity

Comment: How can I do in order to showing any message? I mean, without see "ha ha"...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add`. Hope it will be helpful for you.